# scikit learn logistic regression precision calculation weird warning

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Using scikit-learn with Python 2.7 on Windows. Here is my code and my code has no warning if I change `precision` to `precision_weighted` for scoring parameter. But I do not know what does the warning mean and what is the reason behind scene to explicitly specify `average` to be one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples')? Actually in my case, I want to treat all samples of equal weight, but it seems there is no such option in the 5 choices?

```
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

print cross_val_score(logreg, X, Y, cv=10, scoring="precision")
#print cross_val_score(logreg, X, Y, cv=10, scoring="precision_weighted")
```

Warning message,

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1203: DeprecationWarning: The default `weighted` averaging is deprecated, and from version 0.18, use of precision, recall or F-score with multiclass or multilabel data or pos_label=None will result in an exception. Please set an explicit value for `average`, one of (None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted', 'samples'). In cross validation use, for instance, scoring="f1_weighted" instead of scoring="f1".
  sample_weight=sample_weight)
[ 0.66666667  0.80555556  0.9047619   0.86666667  0.80555556  0.875
  0.94444444  0.80555556  0.82222222  0.80555556]
```

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421413/how-to-compute-precision-recall-accuracy-and-f1-score-for-the-multiclass-case

Comment: @kmario23, thanks for the reference, and I think the root cause if if I need a global number (e.g. global number for precision across all classes), I need to specify the `average` method across class, correct?

Comment: @kmario23, and if I just need a report for precision/recall for each class, it does not matter if I specify `average` method, correct?

Comment: @kmario23, I tried more examples and it seems my issue is different from the other one. I actually met with issue in method `cross_val_score`, this method does not have a parameter called `average` to specify values like, `macro`, `micro`, etc. Any thoughts? Thanks.