# How to deal with this unbalanced-class skewed data-set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I have to deal with `Class Imbalance Problem` and do a `binary-classification` of the input test data-set where majority of the class-label is 1 (the other class-label is 0) in the training data-set.

For example, following is some part of the training data :

```
93.65034,94.50283,94.6677,94.20174,94.93986,95.21071,1
94.13783,94.61797,94.50526,95.66091,95.99478,95.12608,1
94.0238,93.95445,94.77115,94.65469,95.08566,94.97906,1
94.36343,94.32839,95.33167,95.24738,94.57213,95.05634,1
94.5774,93.92291,94.96261,95.40926,95.97659,95.17691,0
93.76617,94.27253,94.38002,94.28448,94.19957,94.98924,0
```

where the last column is the `class-label` - `0` or `1`. The actual data-set is very skewed with a `10:1` ratio of classes, that is around 700 samples have 0 as their `class label`, while the rest 6800 have 1 as their `class label`.

The above mentioned are only a few of the all the samples in the given data-set, but the actual data-set contains about `90%` of samples with `class-label` as `1`, and the rest with `class-label` being `0`, despite the fact that more or less all the samples are very much similar.

Which classifier should be best for handling this kind of data-set ?

I have already tried `logistic-regression` as well as `svm` with `class-weight` parameter set as `"balanced"`, but got no significant improvement in accuracy.

Comment: Since this isn't a programming question you're going to get better responses over at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but got no significant improvement in accuracy.

Accuracy isn't the way to go (e.g. see [Accuracy paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox)). With a 10:1 ratio of classes you can easily get a 90% accuracy just by always predicting `class-label 0`.

Some good **starting points** are:

- try a different performance metric. E.g. [F1-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) and [Matthews correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient)
- "resample" the dataset: add examples from the under-represented class (*over-sampling*) / delete instances from the over-represented class (*under-sampling*; you should have a lot of data)
- a different point of view: [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) is a good try for an imbalanced dataset
- a different algorithm is another possibility but not a silver shoot. Probably you should start with [decision trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) (often perform well on imbalanced datasets)

---

EDIT (now knowing you're using `scikit-learn`)

The weights from the `class_weight` (scikit-learn) parameter are used to train the classifier (so `balanced` is ok) but accuracy is a poor choice to know how well it's performing.

The [`sklearn.metrics`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics) module implements several loss, score and utility functions to [measure classification performance](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). Also take a look at [How to compute precision, recall, accuracy and f1-score for the multiclass case with scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31421413/3235496).

Comment: Actually the test data-set given to me has no class-labels, and I have to predict them, and check accuracy from an online judge, hence I think `sklearn.metrics` can't help me. What should I do then ? Is there a way to only predict whether the `class-label` is 0 or not for a given test-sample ? @manlio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried plotting a ROC curve and AUC curve to check your parameters and different thresholds? If not that should give you a good starting point.

Comment: Can you guide on how to do that ? I am coding in Python.

Comment: @Jarvis sklearn should have it. Here is one of the link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html