# Gridsearch technique in sklearn, python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am working on a supervised machine learning algorithm and it seems to have a curious behavior.
So, let me start:

I have a function where I pass different classifiers, their parameters, training data and their labels:

```
def HT(targets,train_new, algorithm, parameters):
#creating my scorer
scorer=make_scorer(f1_score)
#creating the grid search object with the parameters of the function
grid_search = GridSearchCV(algorithm, 
param_grid=parameters,scoring=scorer,   cv=5)
# fit the grid_search object to the data
grid_search.fit(train_new, targets.ravel())
# print the name of the classifier, the best score and best parameters
print algorithm.__class__.__name__
print('Best score: {}'.format(grid_search.best_score_))
print('Best parameters: {}'.format(grid_search.best_params_))
# assign the best estimator to the pipeline variable
pipeline=grid_search.best_estimator_
# predict the results for the training set
results=pipeline.predict(train_new).astype(int)
print results    
return pipeline
```

To this function I pass parameters like:

```
clf_param.append( {'C' : np.array([0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10]), 
'kernel':(['linear','rbf']),
'decision_function_shape' : (['ovr'])})
```

Ok, so here is where things start to get strange. This functions is returning a f1_score but it is different from the score I am computing manually using the formula: 
F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

There are pretty big differences (0.68 compared with 0.89)

I am doing something wrong in the function ?
The score computed by grid_search (grid_search.best_score_) should be the same with the score on the whole training set (grid_search.best_estimator_.predict(train_new)) ?
Thanks

Comment: Please specify how you are manually calculating the score. Is this a binary or multilabel classification?

Comment: Also change the question title to something more appropriate which is related to the difference in scores. Current title is of very little concern to your actual problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The score that you are manually calculating takes into account the global true positives and negatives for all classes. But in scikit, f1_score, the default approach is to calculate the binary average (i.e only for the positive class).

So, in order to achieve the same scores, use the f1_score as specified below:

```
scorer=make_scorer(f1_score, average='micro')
```

Or simply, in the gridSearchCV, use:

```
scoring = 'f1_micro'
```

More information about how the averaging of scores is done is given on:
 - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values

You may also want to take a look at the following answer which describes the calculation of scores in scikit in detail:-

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31575870/3374996

EDIT:
Changed macro to micro. As written in documentation:

> 'micro': Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true
>   positives, false negatives and false positives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vivek.. My problem is a binary classification one. I know the training data and the labels and I am applying the formula. Also,  after the grid_search performed, in order to make prediction do I need to fit the model again using the best parameters of the grid search to the whole training set ? I assume that the grid search doing cross validation returns the classifier fit to only a part of the training set.

Comment: @Vlad No. The GridSearchCV estimator will refit the whole training data with the best parameters. You can look at the documentation. Actually there is a parameter "refit" in its constructor. By default it's true. So it will refit the whole data supplied to it with the best parameters.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Great help